# Strange behavior getting time using new Date() in java

Tags: java, time, timezone

We're logging some events in our servers, we get the current time of each event, instancing a new Date object. like this `new Date()`

But yesterday something went wrong. the logger shows that this entry was logged at `2012-01-21 14:06:04`, but the event got a different time from the `new Date()`, this one: `2012-01-21 13:06:04`

**There is one hour difference.**

Nonetheless, the other events get a correct time just before and after this buggy event.

**BONUS**

We log the events using this formatter:

```
// Of course, this means that we read our buggy timestamp like: '120121130604'
// but that's irrelevant :p
public static SimpleDateFormat messageDateTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which timezone are you running in/what's the default timezone of your JVM?

Comment: this is the OS timezone: UTC-4:00 GeorgeTown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan

Comment: And the JVM says: user.timezone = America/La_Paz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that your SimpleDateFormat is a public static field, I guess that multiple threads are using it concurrently. But [SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create
>   separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access
>   a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Synchronize its uses, or store it in a ThreadLocal variable, or create a new instance each time.

What you got might be caused by some race condition or other thread-related bug due to the concurrent use of the SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: +1 This is a classic "gotcha". I got tripped up on this early on too. The real villan here is the moron that coded SimpleDateFormat to be non-threadsafe - it's an obvious candidate for caching/reuse between threads

Comment: While I completely agree that this is an issue that should be addressed, I'm skeptical that it caused the OP's issue - especially given that the noted times are exactly 1 hour apart.  Sounds more like a time change issue.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the cause of the problem either. That's why I said "might be caused". But since the logger displayed the same time correctly, at the same instant, this is still my best bet.

Comment: I think this was the cause. Thank you JB!! +1  Some solutions: http://www.codefutures.com/weblog/andygrove/2007/10/simpledateformat-and-thread-safety.html